# Excel VBA - Range select all rows and columns that aren't blank

Tags: excel, vba

Given a table (n x m) how can I select everything in VBA?

Note I may want to store everything in a variable so by select I don't mean highlight but grab everything. The picture is just an example of what data I want

[image]

```
Sub SelectAll()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("instance").Select


ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select

End Sub
```

I apologize if this question was asked before, I couldn't find on this site a solution so a moderator can close this question or link a answered solution.

Comment: When you say "aren't blank" please clarify what you mean.  If there are blanks within the (n x m) table, should they be selected?  Are you just looking for the last column and last row with data?  And does the table always start in Cell A1?

Comment: this is what google showed me on the first hit http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/353392-visual-basic-applications-select-only-cells-value.html the last answer on page 1 seems to be what you want

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am looking to select Range A1:-B5, so the whole table. Even if some fields are blank

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 2D array from the range:

```
Sub SelectAll()

    Dim myTable As Variant

    myTable = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

    '// myTable is now a 2D-Array that you can work with
    '// by using row/column indeces like so:

    Debug.Print myTable(1, 1) '// A1 value
    Debug.Print myTable(2, 1) '// A2 value
    Debug.Print myTable(3, 1) '// A3 value

    Debug.Print myTable(1, 2) '// B1 value
    Debug.Print myTable(2, 2) '// B2 value
    Debug.Print myTable(3, 2) '// B3 value

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I worded my question poorly. I have a table in a empty spreadsheet and I want to put the table in a 2D array. If the table is 1000 rows I can't use this code

Comment: Suppose I wanted the data range to copy or pivot the table. How would I know here if the table ends at myTable(4,5) or myTable(400,500)?

Comment: You use the `UBound()` method :)